Environment variable substitution within a referenced yaml file
I am running a test written in yaml format supported by a testing tool called tracetest. When I run a single test(a yaml file) referencing an environment variable within the yaml as $(environment_variable), the substitution works well. An example below
type: Test
spec:
  id: JJUFEl7SR
  name: App A - Get - Greetings
  trigger:
    type: http
    httpRequest:
      method: GET
      url: ${var:app_a}
      headers:
      - key: Content-Type
        value: application/json
      auth:
        type: basic
        basic:
          username: ${username}
          password: ${password}
  specs:
  - selector: span[tracetest.span.type="general" name="Tracetest trigger"]
    name: Validate Response
    assertions:
    - attr:tracetest.response.body contains "Greetings from Spring Boot App - A!!!"

But when I try to run a suite of tests which is like referencing multiple single yaml files from a parent suite.yaml, an example below -
type: TestSuite
spec:
  id: aeI14Iase
  name: A-B-Test-Suite
  description: Test Suite to run a group of Tests
  steps:
    - ./app_a_get_greetings.yaml
    - ./app_b_get_greetings.yaml
    - ./app_a_b_get_users.yaml


Then these environment variable substitution doesn't happen for those tests. These tests are running inside a kubernetes pod which hosts those environment variables. Can someone suggest a fix for this?

Have you checked that the environment variables (app_a, username, password) are available in the container or not ? In case you didn’t check, try with kubectl exec along with printenv.

Yes, they are available. Thanks for your response. These are being picked when tests are run individually only when the test suite runs when the individual tests are called from within the suite yaml file then they are not picked.
